# Vuejs error after passing axios interceptor

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem that I can't solve with vue.js
I intercept queries that return an error (axios interceptor), and when it passes through this interceptor, the catch of the axios query is still taken into account.

Except that I wait for an error "error.api". which I don't receive, so it generates a console error.

Here is the code:

```html
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, error => {
    let path = '/login';
    switch (error.response.status) {
        case 401: path = '/login'; break;
        case 404: path = '/404'; break;
    }
    store.commit('logout')
    router.push(path);
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

this error

```html
2.js:376 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined
```

And finally, the axios query and the error is generated by the last line (err.api[0])

```html
deleteApi(id) {
    this.$store.dispatch('deleteApi', id)
        .then((res) => {
            this.$toast.success(res.data.success)
            this.deleteApiModal(id)
        })
        .catch(err => this.$toast.error(err.api[0]))
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution but very dirty, which I find repetitive for not much.

It's on each call axios, to put a condition that checks if "err" exists...

I would have preferred to be able to interact on the interceptor to have managed this in only one place.

If someone has a better solution, I'll take it !

```html
deleteApi(id) {
            this.$store.dispatch('deleteApi', id)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.$toast.success(res.data.success)
                    this.deleteApiModal(id)
                })
                .catch(err => { if(err) this.$toast.error(err.api[0]) })
        },
```